# Laravel 4 mapToGroups()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I am trying to map to a group in Laravel 4 but it gives me an error:

```
$groups = $this->messages->mapToGroups(function($message, $key){
            return [
                $message->sent_at => [
                    $message
                ]
            ];
        });
```

The error I get is:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::mapToGroups()
```

Is the function supported in 4.2 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this function in the class wherever you are in need of the mapToGroup (Note that it was adapted from the `mapToGroups` function in L.5.4

```
    /**
 * Run a grouping map over the items.
 *
 * The callback should return an associative array with a single key/value pair.
 *
 * @param  callable  $callback
 * @param  array $array the array to map to group
 * @return Collection
 */
public function mapToGroups(callable $callback, $array)
{
    $groups = (new Collection($array))->map($callback)->reduce(function ($groups, $pair) {
        $groups[key($pair)][] = reset($pair);

        return $groups;
    }, []);

    return (new Collection($groups))->map([Collection::class, 'make']);
}
```

So an example if mapping all users to group will be the following:

```
 $users = User::all()->toArray();
    return $this->mapToGroups(function($message, $key){
        return [
            $message['created_at'] => [
                $message
            ]
        ];
    }, $users);
```

Using this will give you the desired answer.

> PS: I cannot guarantee that this would work on L4.2 but I checked the main functions that `mapToGroups` requires i.e `map` and `reduce` function which is available in [L4.2 Collection class too](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to this tweet; https://twitter.com/laravellog/status/857629925834203136?lang=en

Commit merge; https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18949/commits/1a36e74e4fd1b5a5825242e154154394788c7d3d

This feature was added to laravel `5.4.20` and up.

So, it might not be supported on 4.x